# CSS rules getting omitted after transpiling in Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular8

I upgraded my application from Angular 2 to Angular 8. I noticed few CSS rules are omitted after transpiling the code. Below is my package.json, tsconfig.json and angular.json

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxx-webapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --base-href ./ --deploy-url /Content/Angular/Deploy/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.7",
    "@ngui/datetime-picker": "0.16.2",
    "angular-linky": "1.2.2",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^3.2.4",
    "angular2-color-picker": "1.3.1",
    "angular2-draggable": "^1.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "justified-layout": "^3.0.0",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^6.1.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.2.0",
    "ngx-carousel": "1.3.5",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.0.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/upgrade": "8.2.7",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./Deploy/",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "DigitalJuice-WebApp": {
    "root": "",
    "sourceRoot": "Process/TypeScripts",
    "projectType": "application",
    "prefix": "",
    "schematics": {},
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
          "outputPath": "Deploy/",
          "index": "",
          "main": "Process/TypeScripts/main.ts",
          "polyfills": "Process/TypeScripts/polyfills.ts",
          "tsConfig": "Process/TypeScripts/tsconfig.app.json",
          "assets": [],
          "styles": [
            "Development/css/StoreNew/Store.css",
            "Development/css/StoreNew/CellContainer.css"
          ],
          "scripts": []
        },
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "Process/TypeScripts/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "Process/TypeScripts/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }
            ],
            "optimization": true,
            "outputHashing": "none",
            "sourceMap": false,
            "extractCss": true,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "aot": false,
            "extractLicenses": true,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "budgets": [
              {
                "type": "initial",
                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                "maximumError": "5mb"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actual CSS rule is like this in CellContainer.css(included in the styles of angular.json):

```
.StandardCellOutline {
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(20, 23, 32), rgb(34, 39, 54)), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(44, 46, 51), rgb(140, 147, 168), rgb(44, 46, 51));
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( bottom, #000000, #141720, #222736), -moz-linear-gradient(left center, #2C2E33, #8C93A8, #2C2E33);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #141720, #222736), -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2C2E33, #8C93A8, #2C2E33);
      background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
      padding: 1px;
  }

  .StandardCellOutline:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 1px rgba(001, 122, 204, 0.9);
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(20, 23, 32), rgb(34, 39, 54)), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #4674CD, #4674CD, #4674CD);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( bottom, #000000, #141720, #222736), -moz-linear-gradient(left center, #4674CD, #4674CD, #4674CD);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #141720, #222736), -ms-linear-gradient(left, #4674CD, #4674CD, #4674CD);
  }
```

But after transpiling the code, it becomes:

```
.StandardCellOutline {
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #141720, #222736), -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2C2E33, #8C93A8, #2C2E33);
      background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
      padding: 1px;
  }

  .StandardCellOutline:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 1px rgba(001, 122, 204, 0.9);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #141720, #222736), -ms-linear-gradient(left, #4674CD, #4674CD, #4674CD);
  }
```

You can see rules for Chrome and Firefox are removed. If I just change the order, and put the rule for chrome in the last, then that rule stays. So the problem is only the last rule is included and rest are removed.

```
.StandardCellOutline {
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( bottom, #000000, #141720, #222736), -moz-linear-gradient(left center, #2C2E33, #8C93A8, #2C2E33);
          background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000, #141720, #222736), -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2C2E33, #8C93A8, #2C2E33);
          background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(20, 23, 32), rgb(34, 39, 54)), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(44, 46, 51), rgb(140, 147, 168), rgb(44, 46, 51));
          background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
          padding: 1px;
      }
```

Becomes

```
.StandardCellOutline {
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(20, 23, 32), rgb(34, 39, 54)), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(44, 46, 51), rgb(140, 147, 168), rgb(44, 46, 51));
          background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
          padding: 1px;
      }
```

I tried changing my target, module in the tsconfig to es2015, nothing worked. How to make sure all rules are present in the transpiled code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Angular CLI uses [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) for prefixing browser-specific CSS rules.

A guide for setting up a ruleset using [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) can be found in the [official Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility):

> You can tell Autoprefixer what browsers to target by adding a browserslist property to the package configuration file, package.json:

So simply add the specification of the browsers you want to support to your `package.json`, for example:

```
"browserslist": [
  "> 1%",
  "last 2 versions"
]
```

You can remove the manual vendor prefixing from your CSS codebase, Autoprefixer will take care of that in the build process.

Please note that if you leave vendor prefixes in your CSS codebase, Autoprefixer will remove these during compilation if they are not necessary for 
 the browsers specified in the browserslist.

A full list of supported values for browserslist can be found [here](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#full-list).

Comment: I tried this, it did not work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you make sure that the browserslist ruleset you specified in your package.json actually requires the browser prefixes?

For example: `-moz-linear-gradient` is only required for Firefox < 16, see https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient

Comment: For testing if the browserslist specification in your package.json are working, try specifically targeting a very outdated browser like `"Firefox > 3.6"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the solution recommended by you in the comment and it worked. I now totally understand what is happening in the background. I used the below list of browsers:

```"browserslist": [
    "FireFox > 3.6",
    "Chrome > 10",
    "IE >= 10",
    "Edge >= 12",
    "Safari > 5.1"
  ]```
I know I have specified really old browsers but I was just testing. I will specify more recent ones in the actual code. Thanks again for the help.